# Wordpress and NGINX /wp-admin redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, nginx

My `nginx.conf` has a server blog containing this:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            root /var/www/html/blog;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location /blog {
            root /var/www/html/blog;
            include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

But with these settings when I try to access `/blog/wp-admin` my browser gets stuck in some redirect loop.

If I change the root URLs in `nginx.conf` to `/var/www/html`, `/blog/wp-admin` works, but my post permalinks give me a 404 error.

My WP files are located in `/var/www/html/blog`. I have 'SSL Insecure Content Fixer' plugin installed because my images giving a mixed content error on my site, which has a Cloudflare page rule to always use SSL.

My `WP address` and `WP home` are both set to `http://xxx/blog`.

Anybody fixed something similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the main problem is an inconsistency with your `root` directive. Your PHP configuration has WordPress in `/var/www/html/blog` whereas your static configuration has WordPress in `/var/www/html/blog/blog`.

Assuming that WordPress is installed in the root of `/var/www/html/blog` and that the URIs should be prefixed with `/blog/` for both real files and permalinks, the correct URI for the entry point should be `/blog/index.php`.

The `nginx.conf` file should probably be:

```
root /var/www/html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location /blog {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;
}
```

If you have a conflicting `root` directive within the outer `server` container, the above `root` directive could be placed inside the two `location` blocks **unmodified**.

I would try `/blog/index.php` rather than `/blog/index.php?q=$uri&$args` as the last element of `try_files` because in my experience, WordPress uses the REQUEST_URI parameter to route permalinks rather than the `q` argument as you have implied, but YMMV.

If you do have other applications in this servers root and would like to segregate the WordPress `root` more completely, you might nest the PHP location block like this:

```
location ^~ /blog {
    root /var/www/html;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a hero and a scholar. Could have saved me hours.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but not getting resolved by this. Need some help